# Ionic2 Splashscreen not showing the splash icon

Tags: splash-screen, ionic2

Im trying to build a splashcreen for my ionic2 app.

This is how I put the preference of the splash screen in the config . xml of my app

Here is the sample generated splash icon resources by the ionic CLI

```
<platform name="android">
<icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
</platform>
```

*I cant paste the whole icon src here. Above is just one of the icon src that I have

My problem is that when i run the app on my test device, it loads the Splash screen's background but not the splash icon.

What appears in the middle of the splashscreen is the loading icon of my android device. Can you guys advic or help me??

here is the copy of my apk build 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6gTTV-Ss6qFT1RDSHBBa0hTQjg/view?usp=sharing

Looking forward for your help guys! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently when you start a blank app(ionic2), It already comes with a splash screen and icon.

```
ionic start simpleApp blank --v2
```

then

```
ionic platform add android
```

or

```
ionic platform add ios
```

if you check your directory `simpleApp/resources` all the splash images and icons for both android and IOS are there.